# JSF2 Can i access selectOneMenu value through FacesContext somehow?

Tags: java, jsf

Is is possible to access the value that is in a selectOneMenu through FacesContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of HTML input elements are normally submitted as HTTP request parameters with the input field name as request parameter name. So if you know the JSF-generated HTML input field name, then you'll be able to grab it from the request parameter map.

E.g.

```xml
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="menuId">
        ...
```

and

```
String menuValue = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("formId:menuId");
// ...
```

The usefulness of this is however highly questionable. You normally bind input values to backing bean properties directly by the `value` attribute of `UIInput` components so that JSF will do all the job of gathering request parameters, converting/validating them and updating the model values.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked great. I know it's not the best way to do that and the only reason i'm doing it this way is to solve this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520204/jsf-issue-with-back-button/10520820#comment13611876_10520820. This helped me tremendously. Thanks.